# Firebase: aggregation queries possible via appropriate denormalisation (Android SDK)?

Tags: android, firebase

I understand that one cannot do aggregation queries on firebase to compute statistics and/or return bucketed data similar to a relational db. I wondered if denormalising data could some how replicate aggregation?

I have the following specific problem:

1. I have a set of data with id, subject, score, author, date, tags, locations.
2. I would like to bucket the data in each of these dimensions according to some "similarity" rules e.g. all data on the same day bucketed together, all data located within 10 metres etc., each bucket showing me how many pieces of data in that bucket and the average score.
3. Once I choose a bucket, the underlying ids are retrieved.
4. Given a set of retrieved Ids, I download the data or go back to step 1 to refine using these ids.

I have gone through the Android documentation but cannot work out a way of doing this. Is something like this possible in Firebase? Is it possible via denormalisation or by uploading server code?

I am loathe to give up Firebase as it is so easy and simple to use but aggregation is a core part of my app so hope it is...

Thanks,
Riz

Edit: Edited to make problem clearer.

Comment: It sounds feasible and the bucketing will definitely help reduce the need for (possibly expensive) queries. But it's an incredibly broad question before you actually write some code and model the data. I suggest you give it a spin and post back with a more concrete question if you run into problem.

Comment: Note that "all data location within 10 meter" requires a reference point and lat/lon querying, for which you'll likely want to use [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java).

Comment: Thanks. I don't suppose you know of anyone trying this before, or can point me towards some documentation that may help me get started? Like I said, I'm not sure how to go about doing this yet...

Comment: Are there any stat commands like "count" etc?

Comment: Since you started with "I understand that one cannot do aggregation queries on firebase to compute statistics", I assume you already know that the answer to that is "no". The only ways to know the number of items in a location or query is to either keep a running count (probably using a transaction as I commented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619647/how-do-i-display-the-followers-count-in-real-time-using-firebase/36626491#36626491)) or to download all the children

Comment: Yeah I know, was just hoping I was wrong...

Comment: It's possible GeoFire has something similar to what you need https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-06-23-geofire-two-point-oh.html

Comment: @Ron Harlev: Thanks. Unfortunately my data is not guaranteed to have a location provided so not sure it will work even if I set a radius to "the world".